# Click event Jquery-error

Tags: jquery, ajax

jQuery click is triggering twice (once on page load and on click), but should fire the event when I click on the list item.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>   
    <li id="toolbar-save">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-save"></i>
        <span>Save</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#toolbar-save").click(function() {
        CallValidateMethod();
    });

    function CallValidateMethod(Model) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Validate", "Customer")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            cache: false,
            data: { Model: Model },
        }).done(function() {
            alert('Added');
    });
}
```

Comment: You should not post every thing in title.

Comment: `$("#toolbar - save li")` - that selector doesn't look right.

Comment: if the selector is not correct, it should not even trigger??

Comment: The code you show will never cause the behavior you describe. You'll have to look deeper to see if you find something relevant that could explain your issue (look for `CallValidateMethod` calls for instance)

Comment: please let me know issue for down voting??

Answer (score 0):

Your selector was wrong.

This worked:

```js
$("li#toolbar-save").click(function () {
  CallValidateMethod();
});
function CallValidateMethod(Model) {
  alert("yay");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>   
    <li id="toolbar-save">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-save"></i>
        <span>Save</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#toolbar-save").click(function () {
            CallValidateMethod();
        });

        function CallValidateMethod()
        {

            alert('function called')
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <ul>   
    <li id="toolbar-save">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-save"></i>
        <span>Save</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```